# Expectation of two arbitrary real-valued random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

$X,Y$ are two arbitrary real-valued random variable **on the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},\mathbb{P} )$**. Then the expectation of $X$ could be defined as $E[X]=\int_{\Omega}X(\omega)d\mathbb{P}(d\omega)$. My question is that could the expectation of the product $XY$  defined as $$E[XY]= \int_{\Omega}X(\omega)Y(\omega)d\mathbb{P}(d\omega)$$?

Comment: Yes of course. You have in general that $$\mathbb E[f(X_1,...,X_n)]:=\int_\Omega f(X_1,...,X_n)\,\mathrm d \mathbb P$$ by definition.

Comment: Yes, because $XY$ prescribed by $\omega\mapsto X(\omega)Y(\omega)$ is again a random variable on the space. This rests on the fact that the function $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ prescribed by $(x,y)\mapsto xy$ is Borel-measurable.